# Use meta_query in args for relationship

Tags: meta-query

I found this guide and I'm following it:
https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

But I see that it doesn't work for relationship of Advanced Custom Field. Why?

This is my code:

```
$args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key'          => 'rtp_value',
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => 16,
        'meta_query' => array(
        'relation'  => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'software_relationship',
            'value'   => array('15813', '16013'),
            'compare' => 'IN',
        ),
        ),
    );
```

Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

I'm moving on, but now I have a new problem, how can I handle the meta_query for simple ACF texts?

Looking around I saw that it would need to be done like this:
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

But it doesn't work for me with "=" and "LIKE" operator.

This is my code:

```
$tema_array_args = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($tema_array as $tema_array_key) {
    $tema_array_args[$i] = array('key' => 'tema_slot_machine', 'value' => '"' . $tema_array_key . '"', 'compare' => 'LIKE');
    $i++;
}

$software_array_args = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($software_array as $software_array_key) {
    $software_array_key_id = get_post_id_by_slug(slugify($software_array_key));
    $software_array_args[$i] = array('key' => 'software_relazione_slot_machine', 'value' => '"' . $software_array_key_id . '"', 'compare' => 'LIKE');
    $i++;
}

$volatilita_array_args = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($volatilita_array as $volatilita_array_key) {
    $volatilita_array_args[$i] = array('key' => 'volatilita_slot_machine', 'value' => "'" . $volatilita_array_key . "'", 'compare' => '=');
    $i++;
}

if($filtro_applicato == 'RTP più alto') {

    if($tema == '' && $software == '' && $volatilita == '') {

        $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'          => 'rtp_slot_machine',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
            //'post__not_in'    => array(91690), // esclude l'articolo "inizia qui"
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'cat' => 16,
        );

    } elseif($tema != '' || $software != '' || $volatilita != '') {

        if($tema != '' && $software == '' && $volatilita == '') {
            $relazione = 'OR';
        } elseif($tema == '' && $software != '' && $volatilita == '') {
            $relazione = 'OR';
        } elseif($tema != '' && $software == '' && $volatilita != '') {
            $relazione = 'OR';
        } else {
            $relazione = 'AND';
        }

        $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'          => 'rtp_slot_machine',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
            //'post__not_in'    => array(91690), // esclude l'articolo "inizia qui"
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'cat' => 16,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => $relazione,
                array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                    $tema_array_args[0], $tema_array_args[1], $tema_array_args[2], $tema_array_args[3], $tema_array_args[4],
                    $tema_array_args[5], $tema_array_args[6], $tema_array_args[7], $tema_array_args[8], $tema_array_args[9],
                    $tema_array_args[10], $tema_array_args[11], $tema_array_args[12], $tema_array_args[13], $tema_array_args[14],
                    $tema_array_args[15], $tema_array_args[16], $tema_array_args[17], $tema_array_args[18], $tema_array_args[19],
                    $tema_array_args[20], $tema_array_args[21], $tema_array_args[22], $tema_array_args[23], $tema_array_args[24],
                    $tema_array_args[25], $tema_array_args[26], $tema_array_args[27], $tema_array_args[28], $tema_array_args[29],
                    $tema_array_args[30], $tema_array_args[31], $tema_array_args[32], $tema_array_args[33], $tema_array_args[34],
                    $tema_array_args[35], $tema_array_args[36], $tema_array_args[37], $tema_array_args[38], $tema_array_args[39],
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    $software_array_args[0], $software_array_args[1], $software_array_args[2], $software_array_args[3], $software_array_args[4],
                    $software_array_args[5], $software_array_args[6], $software_array_args[7], $software_array_args[8], $software_array_args[9],
                    $software_array_args[10], $software_array_args[11], $software_array_args[12], $software_array_args[13], $software_array_args[14],
                    $software_array_args[15], $software_array_args[16], $software_array_args[17], $software_array_args[18], $software_array_args[19],
                    $software_array_args[20], $software_array_args[21], $software_array_args[22], $software_array_args[23], $software_array_args[24],
                    $software_array_args[25], $software_array_args[26], $software_array_args[27], $software_array_args[28], $software_array_args[29],
                    $software_array_args[30], $software_array_args[31], $software_array_args[32], $software_array_args[33], $software_array_args[34],
                    $software_array_args[35], $software_array_args[36], $software_array_args[37], $software_array_args[38], $software_array_args[39],
                ),
                array(
                    'relation' => 'OR',
                    $volatilita_array_args[0], $volatilita_array_args[1], $volatilita_array_args[2], $volatilita_array_args[3], $volatilita_array_args[4],
                ),
            ),
        );

    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because of the way ACF stores the relationship data. Have you read the documentation in this topic? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/

Comment: So the only thing to do would be to use only a single post ID at a time...

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve it myself, this is the code I used:

```
if($tema == '' && $software == '' && $volatilita == '') {

    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cat' => $categoria_slot_machine,
    );

} elseif($tema != '' || $software != '' || $volatilita != '') {

    $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'cat' => $categoria_slot_machine,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
            ),
        )
    );

    $i = 0;
    if ($tema != '') {
        foreach ($tema_array as $tema_array_key) {
            $args['meta_query'][0][$i] = array('key' => 'tema_slot_machine', 'value' => '"' . $tema_array_key . '"', 'compare' => 'LIKE');
            $i++;
        }
    }
    if ($software != '') {
        foreach ($software_array as $software_array_key) {
            $software_array_key_id = get_post_id_by_slug(slugify($software_array_key));
            $args['meta_query'][1][$i] = array('key' => 'software_relazione_slot_machine', 'value' => '"' . $software_array_key_id . '"', 'compare' => 'LIKE');
            $i++;
        }
    }

    if ($volatilita != '') {
        foreach ($volatilita_array as $volatilita_array_key) {
            echo $volatilita_array_key;
            $args['meta_query'][2][$i] = array('key' => 'volatilita_slot_machine', 'value' => $volatilita_array_key, 'compare' => '=');
            $i++;
        }
    }
}

if($filtro_applicato == 'RTP più alto') {

    $args['meta_key'] = 'rtp_slot_machine';

} elseif($filtro_applicato == 'Più votate') {

    $args['meta_key'] = '_kksr_ratings';

} elseif($filtro_applicato == 'Nuove slot') {

    $args['order'] = 'date';

}
```

I post because I hope it helps someone :)